# Need to divide string inside list comprehension

Tags: python

Asked of me: By filtering the lowers list, create and print a list of the words for which the first half of the word matches the second half of the word.  Examples include "bonbon", "froufrou", "gaga", and "murmur".

What i have so far:

```
[word for word in lowers if list.(word)(1:len(word)/2:)==list.(word)(len(word)/2::)]
```

Im not sure how to make word a list so I can only use certain characters for this filter. I know this will not work but its my logic so far.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean list *comprehension*?

Comment: Sorry thats what I ment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical Error: You're slicing from index 1 instead of 0 in `list.(word)(1:len(word)/2:)`

Syntax Errors: `list.(word)` is incorrect syntax, and list slicing uses [ ] not ( ). Simply use `word[start:stop]` to break it up

Use:

`[word for word in lowers if word[:len(word)//2]==word[len(word)//2:]]`

Edit: Thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' comment - Use integer division ( // operator ) for Python 3 compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`[word for word in lowers if word[len(word)//2:] == word[:len(word)//2]]`

Comment: To expand on that point: replace `/` by `//`, which will work in both 2 and 3.